# dynamic URL to static

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a PHP based website and it's basically a randomizer. It pull a random image out of the /photos/ folder and displays. The unique pages look like this: 
http://www.domainname.com/picture.php?image=photos/123.jpg

What I'm trying to accomplish using .htaccess is to have it this way:
http://www.domainname.com/picture/123.html

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^picture/([^/]+).html /picture.php?image=photos/$1.jpg [NC]
```

read [this site](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) it was very helpful for me :-)